# Firebase push notification not opening notification page while clicked on notification during app is terminated

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I'm using Firebase push notification. I want to show a notification page while the user clicked on the notification that we send. Its working fine when app is minimized or open. But the navigation not working while app is terminated. While I click on notification using app is terminated it taking on home page instead of notification page.

**Code snippet**

```
  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    final fcmToken = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('token: $fcmToken');
    initPushNotifications();
    initLocalNotifications();
  }
```

```
Future initPushNotifications() async {
await FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    /// listen to background notification
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    ... flutter_local_notifications used here to display notification while app is open
    }
}
```

```
  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if(message == null) return;

    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: message.data.toString());
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Messages(msg: message,))
      );
    });
  }
```

```
Future handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage msg) async {
  if(msg.notification != null) {
    print('notification received ${msg.notification?.title}');
    print('notification received body ${msg.notification?.body}');
    print('notification received data ${msg.data}');
  }
}
```

In main.dart

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  /// firebase notification
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAPI().initNotifications();
```